# How to get the Modulus in LISP

Tags: lisp, modulus

I am learning LISP right now and I haven't found anything on how to get the modulus in LISP. Is there someway to get it inside of a function? I know other languages like Java use % in order to find the modulus, but what does LISP use?

Comment: Which dialect of Lisp is this question about?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about `mod`, from the [page](http://jtra.cz/stuff/lisp/sclr/mod.html):

```
(mod -1 5) => 4                                                              
(mod 13 4) => 1                                                              
(mod -13 4) => 3                                                             
(mod 13 -4) => -3
```

Answer (score 10):

**As an alternative to `mod`, the Common Lisp `floor` function returns modulo as its second value.** This is useful in cases where you are also interested in the quotient.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options:

> **mod** and **rem** are generalizations of the modulus and remainder functions respectively.
>
> **mod** performs the operation floor on number and divisor and returns the remainder of the floor operation.
>
> **rem** performs the operation truncate on number and divisor and returns the remainder of the truncate operation.
>
> **mod** and **rem** are the modulus and remainder functions when number and divisor are integers.

Examples:

```
>  (rem -1 5) =>  -1  
>  (mod -1 5) =>  4  
>  (mod 13 4) =>  1  
>  (rem 13 4) =>  1
```

**Source:** http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mod_r.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Lisp, the command for Modulus function is rem -reminder
Example (rem 13 4) result 1